# how to get invoker class of this method

Tags: c#

is it possible?

i want to get the name of class (like foo) which is invoking my method (like myMethod)

(and the method is in another class(like i))

like:

```
class foo
{
    i mc=new i;
    mc.mymethod();

}
class i
{
    myMethod()
    {........
       Console.WriteLine(InvokerClassName);// it should writes foo
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't help but wonder *why* you would want to know...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhs34xdh.aspx) to work out the caller - but that's assuming there's no inlining going on. Stack traces aren't always 100% accurate. Something like:

```
StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1); // 0 will be the inner-most method
MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
Console.WriteLine(method.DeclaringType);
```

Comment: Is there a property to deliver the stack trace frame by frame, or do we have to parse the string property?

Comment: @Jen: Where do you see any string properties in the same code I provided?

Comment: +1 for mentioning inlining. Unless Attributes are used to explicitly disable it, this will be dangerous to use, it may even work differently in Debug and Release builds.

Comment: @takrl: And also between running in the debugger and running not in the debugger, which is a different thing...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Really? Thanks, I didn't know about that one. I ran into the Debug/Release build scenario once and after that never bothered to try and use this again.

Comment: @takrl: There's a *lot* more optimization going on when you're not in a debugger. And the GC works differently too.

Comment: @Jon: I was thinking of `Environment.StackTrace`, which is a string property -- didn't see your code segment, which explains it very clearly +1

Answer (score 0):

I found the fallowing :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx

```
// using System.Runtime.CompilerServices 
// using System.Diagnostics; 

public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output: 
//  message: Something happened. 
//  member name: DoProcessing 
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs 
//  source line number: 31
```