# Find function Invoker

Tags: c#

I have C# Function like this :

```
private void test(){}
```

Is there any way to find Invoker or caller of a function ?

For example :

```
private void Caller(){
test();
}
```

then how can I understand that test was invoked by Caller ?

Comment: Are you referring to Visual Studio's _Find All References_? Or are you pertaining during runtime?

Comment: If your logic depends on your caller, it should be a different method on your class. They are definitely different behaviors. If you want a debug trace or something go for StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(); and get your stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the names of the methods from call stack.

When you call a function, the name also as the other info is pushed to call stack so the program knows how to return from that function call. You can use that info to obtain the previous function that called your test() function.

To get stacktrace you can use the following:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

Console.WriteLine(stackFrames[1].GetMethod().Name);
```

Comment: You definetly need to look at the link provided by @TheSuperTramp (+1 BTW). Whatever you do, test very thoroughly in all possible ways. This is very likely to bite you in a lot of circumstances, ie. Debug and Release builds may behave differently and while debugging it may be yet another experience. See [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108584/how-to-get-invoker-class-of-this-method/6108600#6108600) and the comments added to it for further reference.

Comment: Good point tarkrl! That was just a quick way of getting the method name. I wouldn't recommend to use that in any production code. What happens if you change your method name for example?

Comment: Don't ask me :) I once tried using this and had the Debug/Release build issue, and I've never used it since. There's other ways to achieve what's needed that are more reliable. But everytime I see this kind of question I point to that Jon Skeet answer, because that sums it up quite nicely.

Answer (score 5):

See [how to get invoker class of this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108584/how-to-get-invoker-class-of-this-method#6108600)

Answer (score 1):

use a parameter in the caller that will be different upon the method call the test.like when you call test from caller use test(1) when you call from another function say from anotherCaller use test(2)

Answer (score 1):

You can a string argument to to test,

```
private void test(string whoCalled){}
```

If and in Caller,

```
private void Caller() {
    test("Caller");
}
```